# Unhandled Promise Rejection: AxiosError: Network Error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Working on a MERN stack project. When trying to access the site on localhost on iPhone Posts are posts are not loading. Working fine on adnroid devices.
[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTpG4.png)

```
const fetchFeedPosts = async () => {
    const URL = `${BASE__URL}api/posts/feed/${LOGGED__IN__USER}`;
    await axios.get(URL)
    .then((response) => setFeedPosts([...response.data].reverse()))
    .catch((e) => console.log(e.response));
}
fetchFeedPosts()
```

Comment: Please provide some code so others can better unsderstand or reproduce the problem. Some detail on what you are trying to acheive would also be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

##### What the error means

When an `Error` is thrown (e.g. `throw new Error()`) it can

- be catched locally (e.g. `try{...} catch(err) { /** here */ }`)
- or be passed on to the calling function. And in that fashion **it bubbles up** from caller to caller until it reaches a catch somewhere.

However, if it continues to bubble up, and there's nothing that captures it by the time it reaches the root of your application or code, then that will result in a so-called "Unhandled" error.

Now, as you may know, promises are more like jobs that drift around. They aren't called from the root of your application. But as they bubble up they can also reach a similar root-point, in which case they become "Unhandled Promise rejections".

##### What to do about it

Unhandled errors or rejections are bad practice though. Errors should be caught somewhere. And without catching them, you can't really know what has caused the error to happen in the first place.

In most cases, you can catch them with a `.catch()` function, (e.g. `yourPromise.catch((err) => {console.err(err)})`)

In case your promise is handled in an async function and waited for with an `await` keyword, then it's slightly different. In that case it makes more sense to use a try-catch block to capture your error.

##### How to apply it to your code

So, the first way of doing it would be to use the `.catch()` function

```
axios.get(URL)
  .then((response) => setFeedPosts([...response.data].reverse()))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

The alternative is to use the `await` syntax with a try-catch. If you want to use this syntax, you have to put the `async` keyword before your function.

```
try {
  const response = await axios.get(URL)
  setFeedPosts([...response.data].reverse()))
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Sure, you could mix the 2, but in most cases that would be rather strange.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. But it seems problem was on defining the API url as "localhost" instead of putting my machine IP addess. Changed "localhost" to "IP address" of system. It is resolved now.

Comment: Exactly, that was my point ! - Because you used the wrong URL, you got an error, that error bubbled up, wasn't caught anywhere and resulted in an Unhandled Promise Rejection. So, the morale is that any kind of error can result in an Uncaught error or uncaught promise rejection. And you should really catch them and print them to the console.error or show some kind of error message to your user. Because if you don't , you can only guess what is going on.

Comment: @JamimMehdi if you add a bit of code to your question that shows how you called your axios , I can tell you how to catch it properly

Comment: Updated the question with axios code.